# mysqli_connect() using mamp

Tags: php, mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

I have MAMP up and running and can run php in my browser, but when i attempt to connect to a MySQL database the connection fails. How do I correct this? I have read that to fix this I need to `"enable php_mysqli extension in PHP.ini. It’s disabled by default. look for the following line: extension=php_mysqli".`

I attempted this but i have multiple `PHP.ini` files and the first one i clicked on did not even have the line `"extension=php_mysli".`

I would like to know how to fix this problem so that i can test websites on my computer and not have to upload to a web server, also once everything is set up properly what are the correct parameters for the **mysqli_connect()** function?

Comment: what do you mean when *have multiple PHP.ini* how many do you have?

Comment: there are 40 files named PHP.ini in the MAMP folder alone

Comment: I am pretty sure just one of them is the real one

Comment: Just installed MAMP to help you, and there is no `php.ini` in MAMP folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed MAMP to help you, and there is no `php.ini` in MAMP folder.

There is just 1 file `php.ini` in folder:

```
C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.3\
```

since php5.6.3 is default version for my MAMP installation.

for my MAMP installation default user for MySQL is `root` and password `root`

Comment: For some reason i have files for many different versions of PHP. But, under MAMP preferences it says i am running PHP version 5.6.2, I opened the php.ini for that version (Macintosh HD/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.6.2/php.ini), searched for the string "php_mysqli" and it was not found.

Comment: how old is your installation?

Comment: *For some reason i have files for many different versions of PHP* so you did something with config files on your own risk?

Comment: I am unsure, I am relatively new to PHP and MySQL. I just ran the following code   `DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
   DEFINE('DB_USER', 'root'); 
   DEFINE('DB_PASS', '');  
    
   
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or 
                    die('could not connect: '. mysqli_connect_error() );`and it returned "could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Comment: for my MAMP installation default user for MySQL is `root` and password `root`

Comment: I have read that it was an empty string, i tried root and it worked. Thank you so much I have literally been trying to fix this for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my mysqli() function seemed to not be working after using it on multiple online servers. But not on MAMP! I followed all above instructions, looking in the php.ini files.

My fix...

I had my MAMP PHP version set to 7.0.0 (standard from install)
I changed this back down to 5.6.13 to test and everything started working correctly!

Im really not sure what caused it, or how to fix it to work with higher php versions.

Maybe something fundemental has changed since version 5.6.13.

Hope this helps someone! and please respond if you know why my problem is happening!